# Write csv data in cpp at each iteration

Tags: c++, csv

I've 3 columns that change at each iteration (clock cycle). I want to store each value of those columns in a csv file. The csv file is Positions.csv.
SUppose the variable I want to store are in: columnA, columnB and columnC variables.
My file will be empty, at each cycle it will be filled with the columnA,columnB and columnC values.
My following code doesn't work, In output file I've just one row.

I want to append at the end of the file columnA,columnB an columnC. I receive different values for those variable at each cycle.

**I need a way to append row in a csv file.**

```
    double columnA , columnB, columnC;
      // LOG START
      std::ofstream coordscsv;
      std::string filename = "Positions.csv";
      coordscsv.open(filename);
      //**************
      std::ifstream  data("Positions.csv");
    
      std::string line;
      while (std::getline(data, line))
      {
          std::stringstream  lineStream(line);
          std::string        cell;
          while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ','))
          {
              coordscsv << cell;
          }
      }
      coordscsv <<  columnA << ", " << columnB << ", " << columnC << "\n";
      coordscsv.close();
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, there's no [mcve] and no actual problem description. Hint though: Opening a file for output will truncate the file, unless you explicitly specify that you want to append.

Comment: The reading from the file (and writing back without any delimiter) is suspicious. If you want to append, open in append mode. If you want to overwrite, just open. Neither case involves reading existing contents.

Comment: Instead of marking the question as solved, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The default argument to `ifstream`s [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) is `ios_base::in`. To append to a file you want [`ios_base::app`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

However, you shouldn't open and close the file in every iteration anyhow. Open it once and unless you want to diagnose errors on closing it you don't need to call `close()` explicitly (the destructor does that already).

Comment: you mean: std::ifstream  data("Positions.csv",ios::app);

Comment: @jerloi no, i mean open it only once outside of the loop (not sure why you removed it from the code in the question)

Comment: in general, what is the correct way to append file in a csv? I did not find an example on stackOverflow.

Comment: @jerloi if you open a file that you want append to then you need to use the `app` flag.

Comment: I also need to avoid that the file exceed a dimension

Comment: That should be a completely new question showing your code that you have written that attempts to solve this new problem. It's totally unrelated to the problem in this question that was asked and answered. Also the answer should be accepted for this question.